# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning and aligning titles

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mnist

I'm trying to put the finishing touches to a small program but I'm stuck on the last 2 items and have gone nowhere for hours. The 2 problems are:

1. I get the following warning when I compile: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
2. I want the title of the plot to be center justified. And even though I have loc=center in the parameters for the title, what it is doing is center justifying over the last image (right most). Here is a link to the image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqqx6.png)

The warning mentioned in #1 above is on Line 15 of my code:

```
import keras
keras.__version__
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

def draw_with_mnist(theString):
  for x in range(0, len(theString)):
    c = int(theString[x],10)
    for i in range(0, 100):
      if (train_labels[i] == c):
        digit = train_images[i]
        plt.subplot(1, len(theString), x+1)
        plt.imshow(digit)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.grid(b=None)
        plt.tight_layout(pad=0.00)
  plt.title(theString+" -- My Name", loc='center')
  plt.show()

draw_with_mnist("34085194")
```

Appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut, apologies. This assignment is actually for a machine learning class, that's why I tagged it